# nginx location alias: static files ignored?

Tags: php, nginx, debian, alias, zabbix

im trying to get the zabbix-frontend to work with nginx. 
this here is my nginx conf:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/test/htdocs;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;


    location /zabbix {

        alias                   /usr/share/zabbix;
        index                   index.php;
        error_page              403 404 502 503 504  /zabbix/index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
            expires                 epoch;
            include                 /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
            access_log      off;
            expires         33d;
        }

    }


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/security;
    include /etc/nginx/main_rules;

}
```

the **php scripts in /zabbix are working**! but files like `/usr/share/zabbix/css.css` are NOT being served (404). in the error log is this:

```
2013/07/19 20:23:33 [error] 13583#0: *1 open() "/var/www/test/htdocs/zabbix/css.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET /zabbix/css.css HTTP/1.1"
```

so as we can see, nginx is looking for the file in the main root directory `/var/www/test/htdocs/` instead of in the alias directory `/usr/share/zabbix/`.

why is that so and how can i fix that?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to separate them locations. /zabbix with alias only and ~ ^/zabbix/*.php$ with fastcgi. Both outside the / location with root.